# Python: how to find out values of all feasible x under constraints

Tags: python

I am writing a code using Python now.

I want to know how to find out values of all feasible x under constraints.

```
x = [x_1, x_2, x_3,…, x_10]
```

constraints:

```
x_i = 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4, where i= 1, 2, ….10 
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 +...+ x_10 <= 15
```

How to find out all the feasible solutions x (domain of x) using python, like `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`, `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` etc ? What should be the code?

Any hint or help would be highly appreciated!

Sincerely,

Eddie

Comment: Get an integer linear programming solver. [lpsolve](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/) or something, I don't know; I haven't looked into the options deeply. It'll solve your actual problem much more effectively than trying to enumerate all feasible solutions.

Comment: It's hard to give you a hint when it's not clear where you're stuck.

Comment: Use [glpk](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) via the [cvxopt](http://cvxopt.org/) module.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to use the naive method of iterating through all possibilities, then you can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). It can give you all the possible solutions:

```
>>> possibles = itertools.product(range(5), repeat=10)
```

Now you can filter out tuples with sum greater than 15 using simple comprehension:

```
>>> solutions = [x for x in possibles if sum(x) <= 15]
```

Or in one line:

```
>>> solutions = [x for x in itertools.product(range(5), repeat=10) if sum(x) <= 15]
```